# How can you use a string variable that has SQL inside a SQL LIKE wildcard pattern expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `SELECT` statement with a `WHERE` clause that uses a `LIKE` wildcard with an expression coming from a variable string that I have built using values from a table. However, although there are no errors, the query is not evaluating correctly to give the expected results, as it is returning all the results records and not applying the condition in the `LIKE` wildcard. The desired result should be fewer records returned as they will be filtered against the `LIKE` wildcard expression.

The variable I have built to use in the SQL query's `LIKE` wildcard is the following, along with the value of the string:

`Declare @TrimmedAgeType Varchar(450);`

`The value is this: '%J%' AND PERM.AgeFilter NOT LIKE '%JS%'`

The SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM #MembershipInfo #PSP
INNER JOIN TRP_ME_PriceStructure PERM 
    ON #PSP.MembershipPriceStructurePK = PERM.MembershipPriceStructurePK
    WHERE PERM.AgeFilter NOT LIKE + @TrimmedAgeType
```

When I hardcode the query with the string value below, I get the expected results returned back.

```
SELECT * FROM #MembershipInfo #PSP
INNER JOIN TRP_ME_PriceStructure PERM 
    ON #PSP.MembershipPriceStructurePK = PERM.MembershipPriceStructurePK
    WHERE PERM.AgeFilter NOT LIKE + '%J%' AND PERM.AgeFilter NOT LIKE '%JS%'
```

If you want to know how I am initially building the string variable value, see below:

```
Declare @AgeType Varchar(450);
Declare @AgeReference varchar(450)
SET @AgeType = CONCAT(@AgeType, '''%' + @AgeReference + '%''') + ' AND PERM.AgeFilter NOT LIKE '
```

Additional Info:

This `@AgeType` variable is being generated inside a while loop
that is looping through a table of Age References. I later change the
name of the variable to `@TrimmedAgeType` as I do some additional work on it to remove the last
occurrence of `' AND PERM.AgeFilter NOT LIKE '`

More Info:
I have a table of memberships with the `AgeFilter` column containing letter references ('A,U,J,C,JS', etc). I want to return all results that do not match the given references in the `LIKE` wildcard pattern. This is because the SELECT query is actually going to be a `DELETE` query and I will delete all records that are returned and do not match the given references in the `LIKE` wildcard pattern.

Hope someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty lost on what your variable looks like and what you are trying to do.  You can use a variable for the pattern in `like`.  You cannot use a variable to store code that you append to a query, unless you are using dynamic SQL.

Comment: `@TrimmedAgeType` in the context you are using it is a *string literal*. You appear to be partly trying to dynamically build your query, ie, using [dynamic sql](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/). You are using a local temporary table however which complicates things further.

Comment: The value of the variable looks like this under the hood: `'%J%' AND PERM.AgeFilter NOT LIKE '%JS%'`. Gordan's last sentence is what I am trying to do. I am appending SQL code (as a variable) to the SQL query's `LIKE` wildcard.

Comment: So basically you have a WHERE clause stored in a variable and you want to magically append the contents of the variable into your query. No, things don't work that way, unless you switch to dynamic SQL, which will cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: `from a variable string that I have built using values from a table.` Why don't you just perform a `NOT EXISTS` against the same rows in this table that you're trying to build a string from? What you're doing seems unnecessarily complex and requires dynamic SQL. I don't agree that dynamic SQL causes more problems than it solves, but I don't use it when I don't have to.

Comment: (And I would offer a more specific suggestion than that, but I can't make sense of how you are constructing your variable _from a table_... I only see code that constructs some part of that variable _from other variables_.)

Comment: Can you add sample data and table script with your tired query. Then we can check. it looks lie your variable is not correctly formed or you are trying to combine static and dynamic codes together. @naz786

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have some filters stored here:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FilterPatterns
(
  PatternID int PRIMARY KEY,
  FilterPattern varchar(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

To simulate the question, let's say we know the PatternID values we're after are 1 and 3:

```
INSERT dbo.FilterPatterns(PatternID, FilterPattern)
  VALUES(1,'%J%'),(2,'%Q%'),(3,'%JS%');
```

We've got some members stored in a #temp table for reasons unknown (how is that populated?):

```
CREATE TABLE #MembershipInfo
(
  MembershipPriceStructurePK int PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Let's insert a few rows to match and not match (note: 30 doesn't exist in the core table).

```
INSERT #MemberShipInfo VALUES(5),(10),(15),(20),(30);
```

Two of these will have matching age filters in the core table, the other two will not. We'll also add a row not in the temp table (25):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TRP_ME_PriceStructure
(
  MembershipPriceStructurePK int PRIMARY KEY,
  AgeFilter varchar(256)
);

INSERT dbo.TRP_ME_PriceStructure VALUES
(5,'foo'),(10,'BobJoined'),(15,'blat'),(20,'NodeJS'),(25,'funky');
```

Now our query can just do a `NOT EXISTS` against the filter patterns table using whatever logic you're currently using to pull values from that table to build the string:

```
SELECT * FROM #MembershipInfo #PSP
INNER JOIN dbo.TRP_ME_PriceStructure PERM 
    ON #PSP.MembershipPriceStructurePK = PERM.MembershipPriceStructurePK
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM 
    dbo.FilterPatterns AS fp
    WHERE fp.PatternID IN (1,3)
    AND PERM.AgeFilter LIKE fp.FilterPattern);
```

- members 5 and 15 are returned
- members 10 and 20 are left out because they matched the filter
- members 25 and 30 are left out because they miss the join

- [Example db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cf9db0c89dfdde22dac637007837ecf0)

Answer (score 0):

Try to hard code the wildcard

```
SELECT * FROM #MembershipInfo #PSP
INNER JOIN TRP_ME_PriceStructure PERM 
    ON #PSP.MembershipPriceStructurePK = 
PERM.MembershipPriceStructurePK
    WHERE PERM.AgeFilter NOT LIKE + '%'+ @TrimmedAgeType + '%'
```

Comment: This won't work because `@TrimmedAgeType` is a string containing `'%J%' AND PERM.AgeFilter NOT LIKE '%JS%'`. Your solution will end up searching for a string not matching the _single_ pattern `'%''%J%'' AND PERM.AgeFilter NOT LIKE ''%JS%''%'` which is not the result the OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

Using Dynamic SQL I have successfully written the query, returning me the expected results:

```
DECLARE @DeleteUnsuitableMemberships varchar(MAX)
SET @DeleteUnsuitableMemberships =
'DELETE #MembershipInfo FROM #MembershipInfo #PSP
INNER JOIN TRP_ME_PriceStructure PERM 
    ON #PSP.MembershipPriceStructurePK = PERM.MembershipPriceStructurePK
    WHERE PERM.AgeFilter NOT LIKE ' + @TrimmedAgeType

EXEC(@DeleteUnsuitableMemberships)
```

I did was the following:

1. Declare a new variable.
2. Set that variable to the SQL query which I have wrapped in apostrophe (').
3. Appended the variable using the `+` operator.
4. Used the `EXEC()` function with the variable placed inside as a parameter.

The value of @TrimmedAgeType is still `'%J%' AND PERM.AgeFilter NOT LIKE '%JS%'`

Thank you all for helping.

Comment: As I showed in my answer (but with made-up table names missing from your question), you really don't need dynamic SQL for this, but please also read [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-1/), [Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-2/), and [Bad Habits to Kick : Using EXEC() instead of sp_executesql](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql).

Comment: You have corrected the query. But be careful with dynamic SQL with where clauses